# How to mask/reduce stevia's metallic after taste?

Tags: sweeteners

I use [SugarLess stevia and erythritol blend](https://www.google.com.au/shopping/product/18023850069614378848?rls=com.microsoft:en-AU:IE-Address&biw=1920&bih=1061&q=sweeteners%20stevia%20erythritol&oq=sweeteners%20stevia%20erithritol&prds=paur:ClkAsKraX_yoiEQI2V0ZdceXKPsut77XvTf6I2rQ_S1YpdNQ4Poo1iZMjqIRPHtuPWHP-wAUAXtBqqm-hsDW4Td5OKsLeqFyPlFNzRdjZeD4thN6pmI2Tl_avRIZAFPVH73emKjbcuUytx8WaBrRSHZCCRnrJg&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIqungwNzfAhVHF4gKHViLApsQ8wII4QI) when I'm baking or making home made ice creams. But in almost all of the things I bake or cook using this product, there is a metallic after taste that lingers for 3-4 minutes. The finished food items taste great but I was wondering if there was a way to somehow mask or reduce this after taste.

[image]

Comment: Stevia is a tight binder with significant genetic variation in how people respond to it: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/can-one-be-taste-blind-to-the-sweetness-of-stevia/74340#74340  I've never met a metallic after taste. With the effects being so variable, you may be on your own here.

Comment: Have you tried using pure stevia?  I'm wondering if it's the other ingredients in the blend producing the aftertaste.

Comment: @FuzzyChef: No, I haven't tried just stevia and it might be my misunderstanding but I thought that it's Stevia that is a tight binder and leaves an after taste.